# Windows version of these openssl commands

Tags: linux, windows, openssl

Would I have to make any changes to these linux commands to make it work on windows? Do all the pipes and redirects work as they do on linux?

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout > key.pub
openssl rsa -pubin -modulus -noout < key.pub
#
# to decrypt mess.enc (message encrypted via javascript)
cat mess.enc | openssl base64 -d | openssl rsautl -inkey key.pem -decrypt
```

I expect I must swap `cat` for `type`, and I am hoping the rest will work as it is. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: It should work (there might be quirks like some special handling of `^Z` by `type` (I'm really unsure on this one), but it shouldn't matter for base64 file).

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent of [cat on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat) will be of great help. Rest of the commands are same and should work fine on Windows.

Comment: Considering that his use of cat is completely superfluous, he won't even need that.

Comment: @Cairnarvon: You are right. In my opinion, he can also do it in multiple steps easily which would be easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it seems to confirm for me that `type` is the correct windows command.

Comment: Can you suggest how I can do it without cat? I need to decode to base64 first right? Can that be done without cat? I would like a cross platform set of commands if it is possible.

Comment: @BillyMoon, you can replace `cat mess.enc | openssl base64 -d` with `openssl base64 -d < mess.enc`. In general, when you're catting a single file straight into a pipe, you're using cat wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent of cat on Windows

```
openssl
cat key.pem
type key.pem
cat=type
```